# How do I turn a "broken" plot into a smooth curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, plane-curves, curves

I developed and solved a differential equation that predicts fluid temperature along the length of a long pipe with time.

Analytical solution is such that it is causing a "discontinuity" in the temperature profile along the depth at fixed time. (This discontinuity travels down the pipe as time progresses. So the picture shown here is just a snapshot frozen at a fixed time at the start of flow.

In actual physical world, this break/discontinuity does not exist.

I want to make it smooth as shown in red in bottom right plot (like red line).

Would you please suggest any method that can fix this problem. 
**

> Suggested method should be reproducible, repeatable and programmable.
>   (I am using VBA)

**

[image]

Comment: Well you need to show your DE so that people can fix it.

Comment: I am interested in a "curve fitting" solution. The solution of DE is correct as I have searched in literature and other papers also have such discontinuities. So a possible way could be "approximating" this result using a graphical technique.

Comment: Also, there is a reason that heat transfer is usually modeled not by an ordinary DE but partial DE.

Comment: I am using PDE.

Comment: cubic splines ?

Comment: @GregMartin Would it be reproducible/repeatable?

Comment: In the physical world, there are things that called shock wave. If the ODE is non-linear, the physical solution can be discontinuous...

Comment: The flow here is slow. There is no shockwave here. Also, I have talked to some experienced people who have worked in industry that they have never seen such anomaly. So this anomaly is only because of the nature of PDE. I want to find out a method to remove this discontinuity and that method has to be reproducible/repeatable.

Comment: Doesn't this suggest that the PDE fails to capture the physical flow, and a different PDE is needed? Sure you can patch things up with splines, but choosing the shape of connecting curve will be an arbitrary decision on your part. Might as well forget the PDE and fit a smooth curve to experimental data.

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY Yes it does but then I want to salvage whatever results it is giving me. This is just one of several cases for which my model predicts temperature. This is the only case that is giving me a discontinuous profile.

Answer (score 0):

A standard technique is indeed to use a piece of a cubic polynomial for connecting broken curve parts. The cubic polynomial is uniquely determined by the function values and derivatives at the end points. This function is well behaved, as proved in lemma 1.1 of the following [German text](https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B6x6GQ82vuH_YnE2STNKZXU1cUk/edit?pli=1), which I wrote a long time ago.

To turn this technique into a "reproducible, repeatable and programmable" method applicable for scenarios like the one in the plot, one can vary the connecting point on the smooth curve, such that $\max(|m_a-m|,|m_b-m|)$ is minimized. Here $m_a$ is the derivative at end point of the discontinuous curve, $m_b$ is the derivative at the connecting point on the smooth curve, and $m$ is the slope of the straight line connecting the two points.

---

A drawback of cubic curves is that they are not well suited for nearly vertical slopes. The plots suggest that this might be the case here. In this case, it is better to work with exponential functions.

In the plot, it looks like only one curve is broken, and the other curve is smooth. In this case, we can add $a \exp(bx)$ to the smooth curve, where $a$ and $b$ are uniquely determined by the conditions that the new smooth curve meets the broken curve at the end point, and that the derivative is continuous at that point. This automatically satisfies the requirement to be a "reproducible, repeatable and programmable" method.

Comment: If I use the cubic polynomial, would it be reproducible/repeatable and automatic considering I am using VBA to write the program?

Comment: @Lee It will not. The result of interpolation will depend on the mesh of the interpolation grid. The red curve you drew makes the transition over the interval of size about 15. That 15 was your choice, it wasn't automatic. The spline will make the transition over the interval comparable to the mesh size: it could be 15 or 0.15, as you choose it. By the way, if you go with cubic spline, I recommend [B-spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline) approximation which is  more suitable for rough data than interpolating cubic splines.

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY what if I write a code that works as follows: 1) Pick the highest temperature point from the top curve. 2)From the bottom curve, discard all the points lesser than the highest temperature point of top curve. 3) Now apply cubic spline (or B-spline approximation). Even if I take this approach do you think it would be an acceptable approach in the eyes of scientific community?

Comment: @Lee How will your code choose the nodes of interpolation? They could be spaced at 10 degrees, 1 degree, 0.1 degree... This is what I keep harping about.

Comment: @Lee There are some options for making such methods "reproducible, repeatable and programmable". The method with the exponential function already satisfies this property without any further modification. For the method with the cubic polynomial, I added a suggestion how to make it reproducible. I'm not sure why you stress VBA.